# Where to define sshfs options when using autofs?

Tags: automount, sshfs, autofs

I have used the following guide:

http://www.tjansson.dk/?p=84

to mount an SSHFS using Automount. The implementation works great. However, I need to add an option to SSHFS as defined here:

http://liquidat.wordpress.com/2008/08/10/short-tip-moving-files-on-sshfs-mounts/

When you use SSHFS in a non-automount way, it's easy to simply add a `-o` option flag into the command. But with the autofs setup, it's not clear where to add in `-o` options.

Where do I specify SSHFS options when using Automount?

Answer (score 0):

In the comma-separated list in `/etc/auto.sshfs`.